# Resolve duplicate fields when inheriting IdentityUser

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity, ef-fluent-api

Help! I am migrating an old ADO application to Entity and Identity Framework's. I have a USERS table, which my analyst does not allow me to change in anything. It has relationships with other context tables and this blessed ID column.
To Use Identity I follow this steps:

1-I've changed the USER entity to inherit IdentityUser.

2-I configured the Identity context to use the context of my application.

3- And I overwritten OnModelCreating to rename AspNetUsers to USERS.

Everything almost works. But I came to a standstill:

If I remove the ID property of my USER class the view calls Action to create with POST etc, but the userManager.Create returns an error stating that the entity does not have the ID that is needed. And if I leave the ID property the view neither calls the Action. And receive a error "System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added."

I believe it happens because I have the ID and Legacy ID of IdentityUser. Can someone give me an idea? I need the ID column in my USERS table.

I try use a nickname, but not work...

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>()
            .ToTable("USUARIOS")
            .Property(p => p.Id)
            .HasColumnName("ID");



        modelBuilder.Entity<USUARIOS>()
            .ToTable("USUARIOS")
            .Property(p => p.Id)
            .HasColumnName("ID");
    }
```

Comment: When you say you tried a 'nickname' but it didn't work, what exactly did you try and what error/problem occurred?

Comment: I was having that problem "System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added." I thought that using xxx pointing the Id property to the ID property of my table would resolve. But nothing happened. The same problem keeps happening. It error happens even before the View call to action.

Comment: Is this where the IdentityFramework ID is a GUID (or similar)? I may have done something similar but don't have the code here, I think I used an intermediary table to map across from the original ID to the Identity ID

Comment: obs.: the xxx ini my comment is in true ".HasColumnName("ID")".  I was "copy and past" to change but forgot and post.

Comment: @d219 This is a possible solution. Thanks! Instead of merging my USERS table with AspNetUsers. I will leave my USERS with the ID and the relationships they already have. And add the IdAspNetUsers to Link with this Identity table. Is this you say right?

Comment: It worked for me, i don't know if it's the best solution (and it wasn't production code) but an option for you at least.